# How can I do registry entry for HKCR in user level by NSIS? I cannot enter any entry in HKCR by user level

Tags: nsis

```
WriteRegStr HKCR ".cax" "@" "Something"
WriteRegStr HKCR ".cax" "content type" "Something"
WriteRegStr HKCR "virtual.document" "@" "Something"
WriteRegStr HKCR ".virtual.document" "content" "Something"
WriteRegStr HKCR "xxxx" "@" "Something"
```

Answer (score 0):

A normal user cannot write to HKCR but they can write to HKCU\Software\Classes and the values you write there are visible in HKCR for that specific user.

```
WriteRegStr HKCU "Software\Classes\.cax" "" "Something"
```

Comment: Sir,Where is it visible in HKCR

Comment: Sir,Its successfully entered in HKCU.But I don't know where is it stored in HKCR.

Comment: HKCR = HKCU\Software\Classes + HKLM\Software\Classes. If you can't see it in HKCR you might be running Regedit as the wrong user or looking at the wrong key if you are running 64-bit Windows.

Comment: Sir, 64bit installer entries are visibled in HKCR.But 32bit entries not visible in HKCR .Is there any reason for that problem?

Comment: That is just how the Registry on 64-bit Windows works. Run the 32-bit version of RegEdit and you will see your values.

Comment: Sir,I enter all the 64bit values to HKCU.from that some values only visible in HKCR not all.like                                                                               
WriteRegStr HKCU "CLSID\{8A654770-204E-4618-94E5-8E775ADA70C2}" "@" "VCollabPresenterAddin64.Connect" this one visible in HKCR also.   But   WriteRegStr HKCU "CLSID\{7995F709-4F38-4AE5-AC1C-3A75BC919E79}\MiscStatus" "@" "32"   this one is not visible in HKCR.WHY?